# How to put HTML table td values in a new line with in same row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I have a html as below

```
<table class="ui-widget" id="lines">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Line Item Number</th>
        <th>Line Item Date</th>
        <th>Unit Cost</th>
        <th>Number of Units</th>
        <th>Line Item Total</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="errortrue">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>20150301</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td class="error">Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE</td>
        <td class="error">Line : 1 INVOICE DATE is a required field</td>
        <td class="error">Line : 1 BILLING START DATE is a required field</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="">
        <td>2</td>
        <td>20150304</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>6</td>          
    </tr>
    <tr class="errortrue">
        <td>3</td>
        <td>20150306</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td class="error">Line : 3 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE</td>
        <td class="error">Line : 3 MATTER NAME is a required field</td>
        <td class="error">Line : 3 BILLING END DATE is a required field</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Here is the jsfiddle ilnk** http://jsfiddle.net/x681ef9r/

I am trying to put all `td` values(with `class='error'`) in new line with in same row

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Line#     |     Date      |   UnitCost    |   NumberofUnits   |     Total      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|1              20150301           1                1                  4         |
|Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE           |
|Line : 1 INVOICE DATE is a required field                                       |
|Line : 1 BILLING START DATE is a required field                                 |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2              20150304           2                2                  6         |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|2              20150306           3                3                 12         |
|Line : 3 NULL Value is not in the defined list for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE           |
|Line : 3 MATTER NAME is a required field                                        |
|Line : 3 BILLING END DATE is a required field                                   |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I tried tweaking `td` values with `class='error'` to `tr` but I didnt get what I intended. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to put them in their own rows to have them span the table, like so:

```
<table class="ui-widget" id="lines">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Line Item Number</th>
            <th>Line Item Date</th>
            <th>Unit Cost</th>
            <th>Number of Units</th>
            <th>Line Item Total</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="errortrue">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>20150301</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="error">
                Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE
                <br/>Line : 1 INVOICE DATE is a required field
                <br/>Line : 1 BILLING START DATE is a required field
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>20150304</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="errortrue">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>20150306</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5" class="error">
                Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE
                <br/>Line : 1 INVOICE DATE is a required field
                <br/>Line : 1 BILLING START DATE is a required field
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

See [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zeroskillz/x681ef9r/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. Is there a way to get table headers count so that I can get rid of `colspan` value `5`

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/x681ef9r/4/

As others answered, you need separate rows and the `colspan` attribute.
This fiddle maintains the same format of one error message per cell.

```
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" class="error">
            Line : 1 NULL Value is not in the defined list  for LINE ITEM TAX TYPE
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Just for reference, if you don't need them to line up **underneath**, you can use the CSS:

```
.error {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: with the CSS the Line messages are not showing up in the format I specified.

Comment: apologies. I didn't look carefully enough at the OP.
Not sure if it is needed, but check the updated fiddle.